# Prove that the radius of convergence of $\log(1+z)$ is precisely $1$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analytic-functions

On Ahlfors' Complex Analysis, he states that the logarithmic series $$\log(1+z)=z-\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3}-\frac{z^4}{4}+\frac{z^5}{5}-...$$ centered at the origin must have a radius of $1$ because "if the logarithmic series had a radius of convergence greater than $1$, then $\log(1+z)$ would be bounded for $|z| < 1$" which is a contradiction. He further says "similarly, if the binomial series were convergent in a circle of radius $>1$, the function $(1+z)^\mu$ and all its derivatives wpuld be bounded in $|z| < 1$," which leads to a contradiction whenever $\mu$ is a positive integer.

I do not get why "if the logarithmic series had a radius of convergence greater than $1$, then $\log(1+z)$ would be bounded for $|z| < 1$." I believe he ia using the Maximum Principle But wouldn't using the maximum principle require not only the assumption that the given series converges but *also* the assumption that it converges to $\log(1+z)$? And similarly, wouldn't it require not only the assumption that the binomial series converges but *also* the assumption that it converges to $(1+z)^\mu$?

Thank you for your help

Comment: If the ROC is greater than one then the series would be continuous on $\overline{B(0,1)}$ which is compact.

Comment: In some ways complex analysis is magical.  This is one of those.  (You are right to worry about series that don't actually converge to the original function for real functions.)  For complex functions, once (complex) differentiable implies [holomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) and equal to its power series on an open disk centered at the center of expansion.  (For "complex differentiable", see [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations).)

Answer (score 1):

If a power series (say centered at $0$) has radius of convergence $R>0$, then it is analytic and thus continuous on the open disk $\{ |z|<R \}$, and in particular is continuous on the closed disk $\{ |z|\le r\}$ for any $0<r<R$. Since that closed disk is compact, this continuous function is automatically bounded on $\{ |z|\le r\}$ and therefore on $\{ |z|<r\}$.